# Efficiently Download Newer files via FTP (Large amount of files with WinSCP commandline)

Tags: batch-file, ftp, winscp

I am currently creating a small process that will download any new or updated file from an FTP(not SFTP) location to a local drive. I have written a small batch script along with WinSCP, but it takes FAR too long. There are around 200k files and 16k folders on the FTP. It takes just under an hour to check every file and folder, not including any time downloading any new/updated file. From what I understand, WinSCP compared file modification dates of every single file and folder, which is why it takes so long. I'm not sure where to go from here.

I am using WINDOWS 10.

Is there a better way to go about synchronizing these? Possibly check FTP drive if anything has been changed, if so, find the change and download it? Will post pics of batch if needed.

Thank you!

Comment: *"Possibly check FTP drive if anything has been changed"* - That's what WinSCP does, right?

Comment: In a way, yes. WinSCP checks every single file, one by one, and then downloads the new/updated files. The problem is that there are so many files that it takes about an hour just to scan the files to check if anything is new. I'm looking for a way to speed this up or make it more efficient.

Comment: Search for rsync.

Comment: from what I have read rsync does not work with FTP

Comment: True. If your only interface is FTP, there's nothing better than what WinSCP does.